# Do I have to release a NSLocalizedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The question is simple. Do I need to release a NSLocalizedString? For instance:

```
NSString *internetMessageTitle = NSLocalizedString(
@"You are currently not connected to a internet network"
@"Title of the message that tells the user there is no internet network");
```

Because I did this:

```
NSLog(@"Retain count of InternetMessageTitle is: %d", 
                                             [internetMessage retainCount]);
```

But it prints a retain count of 2. However I have read that the retainCount attribute is not very reliable. Should I release it twice?

And yes I have read the memory management rules and guide of the documentation but I don't see here any indication of NARC (NewAllocRetainCopy). I am still a beginner so I don't really know how NSLocalizedString makes strings.

Thank you!

EDIT1: I use this variable in a UIAlertView I don't know if the retainCount is increased there when I use it. And even when the alert is not used (inside an if, and if the if is skipped it isn't used) the retainCount is still 2 according to NSLog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you must not release it. If you check how NSLocalizedString is defined you'll see:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

That its normally a call to NSBundle's method that returns autoreleased string

> I use this variable in a UIAlertView
>   I don't know if the retainCount is
>   increased there when I use it. And
>   even when the alert is not used
>   (inside an if, and if the if is
>   skipped it isn't used) the retainCount
>   is still 2 according to NSLog.

Yes, labels in UIAlert retain their content strings, but you should not worry about that - they will release them when get destroyed.

Comment: Then why is the retainCount 2? Or it is only misleading? And why doesn't it crash if I release it?

Comment: `retainCount` should rarely, if ever, be used for debugging. If you look at Apple's own documentation for it you'll realise it's often not very useful.

Comment: I guess: 1 retain - is for creation (will be handled by autorelease pool), 2nd retain - by alert's label - will be handled in labels destructor. Not sure why you don't get crash... may be alert does not get deallocated at that time - your program may probably crash later, say after alert is closed (and so its dealloc method called)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there's no NARC -- so you already know the answer is no.

And what you've read about retain counts? Heed it. Never look at the retain count as useful info. **Never look at it all.**

And FFS don't do something insane like calling `release` on an object several times just because you think it has a retain count > 1. That stuff is absolutely guaranteed to mess you up.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) are very simple. There's only one of consequence: all alloc/new*/*copy* calls must be balanced by a call to auto-/release. You're not calling a method or function named "alloc", starting with "new" or containing "copy", thus you shouldn't release.

Even simpler than following the memory rules is to use [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) (object or [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698239/objective-c-allocation-in-one-thread-and-release-in-other/4698273#4698273)) when possible.